# java: package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist for log4j 2.13.3

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2

Thanks in advance !

I am trying update log4j 1.2.12 to 2.13.3, but getting an error saying  `java: package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist` . My pom file looks like  below.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

And I am importing in java class as below

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

I also tried importing it as follows

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

but no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated !

Thanks